# How to solve the bad certificate error in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, info.plist

I'm trying to use the `MapKit framework` in my app. I need to get the points for route. For that I write the following:

```
let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculate { response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error getting directions ", error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            guard let response = response else { return }
            completion(response.routes[0])
        }
    }
```

However, I get the error message:

> Error getting directions  Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be
>   connecting to a server that is pretending to be “gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com”
>   which could put your confidential information at risk." 
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/directions.arpc,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000014bce40 { Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" 
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
>   _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9843, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9843, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=()}},
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9843, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(),  NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You
>   might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com” which could put your confidential information
>   at risk., NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/directions.arpc,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3})

I have already edited the Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

That's what the browser shows me:
[image: That's what the browser shows me]

Comment: I can't imagine apple's tiles cdn to have an invalid cert tbh, check the time and date on your device is correct, this can be a common, less known cause of a valid cert showing as invalid as the dates don't match up

Comment: @Scriptable I have checked the date and time twice, everything is correct. I have added a picture to the question of what the browser shows to me. It says that the certificate is invalid too

Comment: The same issue. @Anastasia, the problem is not in your device.

Comment: @Anastasia this works for me when I'm in USA VPN. Hope this will help at least in debugging.

Comment: @Alexey, thank you for a VPN suggestion, with VPN on everything is perfect and no errors at all. Hope, they will fix it soon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the bug report to Apple the problem was fixed, now everything is working without VPN on.